# Apache Beam DirectRunner enable multi threaded processing of different ParDo/DoFn

Tags: java, kotlin, apache-beam

I'm using Apache Beam with DirectRunner. I have 5 DoFns wrapped with ParDos that are applied one after another. When Pipeline is run(), first DoFn processes all its work, then second, then third. I would like the second DoFn to start working as soon as the first will emit an output so that processing will be parallel, as currently at most one DoFn is working at any given time (related: [Thread Synchronization for DoFn in Apache Beam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57130258/thread-synchronization-for-dofn-in-apache-beam)).

```
    val pipelineOptions = PipelineOptionsFactory
        .fromArgs("--streaming", "--experiments=use_runner_v2")
        .withValidation()
        .create()
        .`as`(DirectOptions::class.java)

    pipelineOptions.isBlockOnRun = true
    pipelineOptions.isEnforceEncodability = true
    pipelineOptions.isEnforceImmutability = true
    pipelineOptions.targetParallelism = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() * 2
    pipelineOptions.appName = name

    val pipeline = Pipeline.create(pipelineOptions)

    pipeline
        .apply(...)
        .apply(...)
        .apply(...)
        .apply(...)
        .apply(...)
        .apply(...)

    pipeline
        .run()
        .waitUntilFinish()
```

Answer (score 0):

The Java DirectRunner already executes each stage independently and asynchronously. It has a fixed number of working threads. What you are experiencing is caused by your input all being in a single bundle, so they are all committed together. The DirectRunner does not re-bundle inputs, so the bundle will pass through the pipeline together.

If you have a true streaming unbounded data source, the DirectRunner will process each bundle as it is emitted from the source.

Comment: I have bounded data, but it's big and I would like to process it via streaming. I have already passed --streaming argument but it seems to have no effect. I can implement UnboundedSource instead of BoundedSource, but isn't it a walk around?